# How do I get the list of pages that I am admin of using PHP SDK 5 and Graph 2.5?

Tags: php, facebook

I have tried using FB Graph API Explorer (me?fields=id,name,groups,accounts) and it returns just the id and name.  I am admin to 4 groups.  I have a test app set up and I get an "Get User Access Token" with "user_managed_groups" under "USER DATA PERMISSIONS".  I do not know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: please elaborate your question further

Comment: Your title is about pages, but then the question itself talks about groups – so which one is it?